# Hangfire does not recognize database context

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I'm trying to add Hangfire to do work to send emails with a weekly digest for administrators.

I have background scheduler

```
{
    public class BackgroundScheduler : IBackgroundScheduler
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public BackgroundScheduler(IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager,IMediator mediator, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }

        public void SendWeeklyDigestEmail()
        {

                _mediator.Send(new WeeklyDigestEmailCommand());
            
        }

        public void ScheduleRecurringTasks()
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SendWeeklyDigestEmail(), "0 7 * * MON");
        }
    }
}
```

which sends the command to the command handler. The command is empty so I'm going to show you directly the command handler:

```
  public class WeeklyDigestEmailCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<WeeklyDigestEmailCommand>
    {
        private readonly IBackofficeDbContext _context;
        private readonly IEmailNotification _emailNotification;
        private readonly ITemplateProvider _templateProvider;
        private readonly FrontendConfiguration _frontendConfiguration;
        public WeeklyDigestEmailCommandHandler(IBackofficeDbContext context, IEmailNotification emailNotification, ITemplateProvider templateProvider,
            IOptions<FrontendConfiguration> frontendConfiguration)
        {
            this._context = context;
            _emailNotification = emailNotification;
            _templateProvider = templateProvider;
            _frontendConfiguration = frontendConfiguration.Value;
        }

        public async Task<Unit> Handle(WeeklyDigestEmailCommand command,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var usersByTenant = await _context.Users
            .Include(x => x.Role)
            .Where(x => x.Role.Name == Constants.Roles.TenantAdministrator)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            Console.WriteLine(usersByTenant.Count);

            var usersByTenantGrouped = usersByTenant
                .GroupBy(x => x.TenantId);


            var subject = "Weekly digest email";
            var template = _templateProvider.GetTemplate(EmailTemplateType.WeeklyDigestEmailTemplate);


            foreach (var tenantGroup in usersByTenantGrouped)
            {
                var tenantAdmins = tenantGroup.ToList();
                var tenantAdminsIds = tenantAdmins.Select(ta => ta.Id).ToList();


                var newCustomersCount = await _context.Customers
                    .Where(c => c.Created >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) && tenantAdminsIds.Contains(c.CreatedBy))
                    .CountAsync(cancellationToken);

                var newProjectsCount = await _context.Projects
                    .Where(p => p.Created >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) && tenantAdminsIds.Contains(p.CreatedBy))
                    .CountAsync(cancellationToken);

                var completedProjectsCount = await _context.Projects
                    .Where(p => p.LastModified >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) || p.Created >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) && p.Status == ProjectStatus.Completed && tenantAdminsIds.Contains(p.CreatedBy))
                    .CountAsync(cancellationToken);

                var completedProjectTasksCount = await _context.ProjectTasks
                    .Where(t => t.LastModified >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) || t.Created >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) && t.Completed && tenantAdminsIds.Contains(t.CreatedBy))
                    .CountAsync(cancellationToken);

                var overdueTasksCount = await _context.ProjectTasks
                    .Where(t => DateTime.UtcNow >= t.DueDate && tenantAdminsIds.Contains(t.CreatedBy))
                    .CountAsync(cancellationToken);
                Console.WriteLine("Weekly digest email.");
                foreach (var tenantAdmin in tenantAdmins)
                {
                    var body = template.FillTemplate(tenantAdmin.Name, newCustomersCount, newProjectsCount, completedProjectsCount, completedProjectTasksCount, overdueTasksCount, _frontendConfiguration.Url);

                    await _emailNotification.SendEmailAsync(new EmailMessage
                    {
                        To = tenantAdmin.Email,
                        Subject = subject,
                        Model = body,
                    }, EmailTemplateType.WeeklyDigestEmailTemplate);

                }
            }


            return Unit.Value;
        }
```

I made httppost with this command for testing purposes, and when i send it through the controller, it is sending emails and everything is working fine. But when i try to run it through hangfire, it stops running after the usersByTenant variable because it seems like it is not finding any tenant administrators, which is strange because when i run it, i get them and the program goes on. I tried initializing the dbcontext and hangfire after that, but it is still not working.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BackofficeDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString")));

// Add Hangfire
builder.Services.AddHangfire(config =>
{
    config.UseSqlServerStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString"));
});

//Register background scheduler
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBackgroundScheduler, BackgroundScheduler>();

var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var backgroundScheduler = serviceProvider.GetService<IBackgroundScheduler>();
backgroundScheduler.ScheduleRecurringTasks();
```

I also tried making it in a service scope, but i am getting an error that it is disposed:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
```

I also cannot use ContextFactory, because i only have access to the interface of the db context, as the implementation is in another project in the solution. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change implementation of `ScheduleRecurringTasks` to:

```
public static void ScheduleRecurringTasks()
{
   RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IBackgroundScheduler>(x => x.SendWeeklyDigestEmail(), "0 7 * * MON");
}
```

This will fix two things for you:

1. You will not anymore need to build the service provider by your self, so you can remove the following and change it with a call to the static method:

> var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider(); var
> backgroundScheduler =
> serviceProvider.GetService()

2. Since you have register `BackgroundScheduler` on DI with an interface, the activator of the job should try to find it using the interface, first implementation that you did will tell the activator to find it using the class type.

> builder.Services.AddScoped<IBackgroundScheduler,
> BackgroundScheduler>();

Comment: i cannot use getservice without any arguments

Comment: you don't need getservice, just call the static method ScheduleRecurringTasks()

Comment: 'IBackgroundScheduler.ScheduleRecurringTasks()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: Remove ScheduleRecurringTasks method from the interface

Comment: ok, but that does not solve the problem that it is not getting the items from the context?

Comment: Do you have services.AddHangfireServer(); somewhere in that application?

Comment: yes, in the app configuration